# mkdir nant permissions

Tags: permissions, networking, nant, mkdir

I need to use mkdir on a network path, which is on a different domain. I can login into the network properly, however nant is not able to. I setup a network drive on the system where nant runs, however it still cant access it. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide more info. How was the NAnt script triggered? From a service? If 'yes': Under what account does the service run? Local admin? Or was the script triggered interactively from command-line? Has the logged in user rights to access network path?

Comment: It was triggered from CruiseControl, which runs under my current domain credentials. I guess that explains it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sorry for asking again but with your current domain credentials you have permission to create a directory?

Comment: no, only if I login with my credentials to the other domain.

Answer (score 2):

Mount the shared folder with valid credentials:

```
net use J: \\servername\share  password /user:username
```

Copy files to J: like you normally would.

When your all done disconnect the mapped drive.

```
  net use J: /d
```

Comment: But then I would have to disclose my password? Besides that I created the shared folder manually using my credentials and told it to save them.

Comment: yes you would need to store a password in the nant script, the shared folder could be setup with any network account, so making a seperate account for this might be an option.